# Capture current time but reset the minutes to zero without dealing with timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimezone

In my core database, when I update information from the server, I capture the current time and save that in a core database field.  I know the server updates information at the top of the hour, so I want to rate limit the requests to the server to once an hour, but also grab the most recent data from the server.

For example, say on the hour the server updates its data.

On my app, I can refresh at any point in time.  Say I grabbed data at 7:55am.  While I want to limit the frequency of update requests from the app to once an hour, I also want to have the latest data as soon as its available.  So instead of storing a timestamp of 7:55, I would want to store 7:00am, so if I refresh in 10 minutes, I would at least get the next update.

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
//calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:oldDate];
comps.minute = 00;
comps.second = 00;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

return newDate;
```

The above code does not work because once I call NSCalendar, timezones are involved.  Is there a way to do this without involving NSCalendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncating a date/time to the full hour *necessarily* requires the specification of a time
zone. As an example, [Indian Standard Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) is GMT+05.30, so "7.55am GMT" is the same as "1.25pm IST".

If the server updates its data at every full GMT hour, the next update would be at "8.00am GMT". But if the server resides in India and updates its data at every full IST hour, the next update would be "2.00pm IST" which is "7.30am GMT".

So to compute the "full hour" you have to know which time zone the server uses. If the
server update is done every full GMT hour, then adding

```
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

would be the right thing.

Btw., a slightly shorter way to compute the start of the current hour is
using the `rangeOfUnit:...` method of `NSCalendar`:

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; 
NSDate *newDate;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSHourCalendarUnit startDate:&newDate interval:NULL forDate:oldDate];
return newDate;
```

Comment: That did not work as I noted in the code where I commented out GMT.  The issue turned out to be that I was missing the component flag to include the hour and minute.

Comment: @AmroYounes: Yes, I did not note that before and only tried to answer your question about *dealing with time zones* as specified in the question title. - Note that it is sufficient to add NSCalendarUnitHour.

Comment: I tested the new solution you added with using rangeOfUnit and it worked.  I'm reading up on this to understand why it works.  Thanks

Comment: I will also be accepting my answer as it allows flexibility to set the minutes to a specific time for those whose servers for example take x minutes to update and you want to allow updates at specified time during the hour.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like [YLMoment](https://github.com/YannickL/YLMoment):

```
YLMoment *currentTime = [YLMoment now];    
YLMoment *lastServerTime = // load a YLMoment you saved to NSUserDefaults or default to current time

if (currentTime.hour > lastServerTime.hour)
{
    // Do your updates
    // Get the new server time and save it to NSUserDefaults
}
```

You may need to throw a check in there to make sure you only run the update once an hour (a BOOL value of "didUpdateFromServer" that resets to NO every time an update is performed, for example), but saving the update upon success in that if statement might do the job.

**Edit:** since you're wanting to explicitly ignore timezones, you might not want to pull the server time at all - just store the last updated time in NSUserDefaults and only perform that server call if the `>` succeeds. This is of course assuming you aren't worried having your users retrieve data the instant it becomes available, as Martin indicates with non-hour-offset timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, I added the missing components in unitFlags to include Hour, minutes, and seconds.  I also set the calendar to GMT.  This seems to preserve the TZ.  This solution has the advantage of allowing one to set the variables to whatever you wish.

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay| NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSCalendar *calendar;
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:oldDate];
//comps.hour   = 23;
comps.minute = 00;
comps.second = 00;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```